# Maximizing Code Performance for Shapely

Tags: performance, shapely, code-review

I've written this code in order to calculate the percent cover of grassland within a national park, within 20km^2 of points of recorded occurrences for a species. It is designed to only consider the areas within the park, and not those outside. It works, except for one huge issue... it's *incredibly* slow. I think I've tracked it down to the `avail_lc_type = pt_buffer.intersection(gl).area`. The gl polygon has > 24,000 polygons in it. It is a raster to polygon transformation (it has been dissolved), so it has a lot of little polygons within. Right now it's not a huge problem since I'm running it on ~300 points (still takes > 1 hr), but I plan to run it on a few million later, so I need to improve it.

Any ideas?

```py
import numpy as np
import pprint
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import*
import fiona
from fiona import collection
import math

traps = fiona.open('some_points.shp', 'r') #point file: focal points around which statistics are being derived

study_area = fiona.open('available_areas.shp', 'r') #polygon file: represents area available for analysis
for i in study_area: #for every record in 'study_area'
        sa = shape(i['geometry']) #make a variable called 'sa' that is a polygon

grassland = fiona.open('land_cover_type_of_interest.shp', 'r') #polygon file: want to calculate percent cover of this lc type within study_area, and within areaKM2 (next variable) of each focal point
pol = grassland.next()
gl = MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in grassland]) 

areaKM2 = 20 #hyp home range size of specie of interest

with traps as input:
    #calculate initial area in meters, set radius
    areaM2 = areaKM2 * 1000000
    r = (math.sqrt(areaM2/math.pi))
    #begin buffering and calculating available area (i.e. within study area) for each point
    for point in input:
        pt_buffer = shape(point['geometry']).buffer(r)
        avail_area = pt_buffer.intersection(sa).area
        #check and adjust radius of buffer until it covers desired available area within study area
        while avail_area < areaM2:
            r += 300
            pt_buffer = shape(point['geometry']).buffer(r)
            avail_area = pt_buffer.intersection(sa).area
        #then, calulate percent cover of land cover type of interest within adjusted buffer area
        #print to check
        avail_lc_type = pt_buffer.intersection(gl).area
        perc_cov = (avail_lc_type/areaM2) * 100
        print perc_cov
```

---

Using the answer from @MWrenn I was able to profile my code and came up with this:

```
55.3555590078
         415 function calls (365 primitive calls) in 48.633 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001   48.632   48.632 <module1>:15(neighb_func)
        1    0.000    0.000   48.633   48.633 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 <string>:531(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1118(debug)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1318(getEffectiveLevel)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1332(isEnabledFor)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _abcoll.py:483(update)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:68(__contains__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:128(__instancecheck__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:148(__subclasscheck__)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:195(_is_empty)
       11    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 base.py:202(empty)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.000 base.py:212(__del__)
       25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:231(_geom)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:235(_geom)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:313(geometryType)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:316(type)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 base.py:383(area)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 base.py:443(buffer)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:46(geometry_type_name)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 base.py:52(geom_factory)
        3    0.000    0.000   48.626   16.209 base.py:529(intersection)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:106(_dump_int)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:150(_dump_str)
     12/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:179(_dump_tuple)
     24/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:202(_dump)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:332(dump)
     10/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:360(dumpable)
     14/8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 brine.py:369(<genexpr>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 channel.py:56(send)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collection.py:186(filter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collection.py:274(__iter__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collection.py:364(closed)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:37(__init__)
       25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:53(__setitem__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 compat.py:17(BYTES_LITERAL)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 coords.py:20(required)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 geo.py:20(shape)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 geos.py:484(errcheck_predicate)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 impl.py:43(__getitem__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 point.py:124(_set_coords)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 point.py:188(geos_point_from_py)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 point.py:37(__init__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 protocol.py:220(_send)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 protocol.py:227(_send_request)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:241(_box)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 protocol.py:438(_async_request)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stream.py:173(write)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 topology.py:14(_validate)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 topology.py:33(__call__)
        3   48.626   16.209   48.626   16.209 topology.py:40(__call__)
        2    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 topology.py:57(__call__)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {__import__}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_ctypes.byref}
      6/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {all}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {hasattr}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
       31    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {locals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.sqrt}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pack' of 'Struct' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {next}
```

I'm still trying to figure out exactly what it means, but I think it's telling me that the `intersection` function is taking ~16 seconds each time it's called. So, per @gene 's suggestion, I'm working on using a spatial index. I just have to figure out how to get libspatialindex going so that I can use Rtrees.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index). Without an spatial index, you must iterate through all the geometries. With a bounding spatial index, you iterate only through the geometries which have a chance to intersect the other geometries.

Popular bounding spatial indexes in Python:

- [R-tree index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (Python modules [Rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) or [pyrtree](https://code.google.com/p/pyrtree/))
- [Quadtree index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) ([Quadtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Quadtree/0.1.2) module)

Examples:

- [rtree examples](http://toblerity.org/rtree/examples.html)
- [rtree python polygon index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42931/rtree-python-polygon-index)
- [Best way to find the polygons crossed by a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4635/best-way-to-find-the-polygons-crossed-by-a-line/4646#4646)
- [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/103066#103066) with Fiona.
- [libspatialindex (and Rtree) Fast and fun spatial indexing for bounding boxe](http://toblerity.org/rtree/presentations/geomeetup-12-06-2012-hobu/#/) with Fiona
- [Using Rtree Spatial Indexing With OGR, shapely and Fiona](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/05/12/using-rtree-spatial-indexing-with-ogr/) with Fiona
- [Trying a Python R-tree implementation](http://skipperkongen.dk/2013/02/18/trying-a-python-r-tree-implementation/)
- [Search Nearby using Rtree](http://gaganb.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/search-nearby-using-rtree/)

In your script:

1. Why

   - `from fiona import collection`if you `import fiona` and use only `fiona`?
   - `import numpy as np` if you are not using Numpy but `math`?
   - `import shapely` if you specify `from shapely.geometry import *`?
2. If `sa` is a list, then use `sa = [shape(i['geometry']) for i in for i in study_area]`. If not, you need a condition; otherwise `sa` will be the last feature of `study_area`.
3. Why `pol = grassland.next()` if you read the shapefile with  `MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in grassland])`?

Some suggestions:

You use the grassland and trap variables once, so you don't need them

```py
gl = MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in fiona.open('land_cover_type_of_interest.shp')])
```

and

```py
for point in fiona.open('some_points.shp'):
```

Comment: I'm new to Python, and as a result my ignorance shows. A lot of this script is repurposed from other online sources. Clearly my understanding of python leaves something to be desired. As for 1 - I was using `collection` in an earlier version of the script and left that in there. Will remove - ditto for `numpy`. I imported `shapely` because I planned to use parts other than `geometry` later on in the same module. 3&4 - I'm still learning exactly how `fiona` reads in files, so where I came across something that worked online, I left well enough alone. Lastly, I'll look into your suggestions.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the use of spatial indexes. If I create a spatial index for a polygons file, will it be "attached" to said file in some way, or will the index stand alone? That is, after creating a spatial index for my polygon file, can I just run Shapely's intersect() function on the polygon file again, and get better results? Or do I need to run it on the index, then relate those results back to my original polygon file? I've looked at the documentation, but it's not helping me here.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to optimizing code, don't guess - profile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script.

Just looking at your code, a similar statements :

```
avail_area = pt_buffer.intersection(sa).area
```

seems like it would get called even more than the statement you identified, since it's nested in yet another loop.

Also, you might look into prepared geometry with shapely - http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations
It supports limited geometric operations, so it may not be a drop in replacement for what you're looking to do.